# how to use coverage run --source = {dir_name}

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, python-3.6, coverage.py

I have certain files in a directory named `benchmarks` and I want to get code coverage by running these source files.

I have tried using source flag in the following ways but it doesn't work.
`coverage3 run --source=benchmarks`
`coverage3 run --source=benchmarks/`

On running, I always get `Nothing to do`.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`coverage run` is like `python`.  If you would run a file with `python myprog.py`, then you can use `coverage run myprog.py`.